# How to referencing other (multi)module's resouce on test code[in Android-Studio or IntelliJ]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, android-testing

#### android project dir

```
my-app/
├─ app/
 │  ├─ test/ <- test here
 │  ├─ main/
 │  ├─ androidTest/ <- test here
├─ common_res/
 │  ├─ main/
 │  ├─ res/
 │      ├─ values/ <- reference resources
        … other resources   
…
```

In IDE(in Android-Studio), *It cann't referencing resource like string or drawable and so on.*
it show  **Red sign**

#### (But unit or UI test works well)

I tried like below but fails

```
(app/build.gradle) 
dependencies {

    ...
    implementation project(":common_res")
    testImplementation project(":common_res")
    androidTestImplementation project(":common_res")
    
}
```

and tried sourceSet(in app/build.gradle) way but i didn't achieve my goal.

(I am not understand well gradle sourceSet)

#### screenshot

All the red signs in dir or files has referenceing resources.
[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I face kind of similar issue

Comment: I answered below. I used full path of other module's resoure like `com.example.untitled.common.R.String` in `app` module test.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any solution (setting) for this problem.

Just using like this before find solution.

#### Basic use

If using `R.id.[something]` in app resources , in same test-code.

```kotlin
getString([my-app].common_res.R.string.[something])
```

or not using in app resource

```kotlin
import [my-app].common_res.R
...
getString(R.string.[something])
```